# Can I upsert() on a HasMany relation?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am looking to bulk create or update models in my table via a HasMany relation:

**App/Models/Relation**

```
public function data() : \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Data::class);
    }
```

**App/Http/Controllers/DataController**

```
$relation->data()->upsert($data,'id',['data']);
```

However this fails with an error stating undefined 'relation_id'.  I would have expected this to be set already, given that I am calling the `upsert()` on the relationship?

Using CreateOrUpdate only takes one model at a time, I need to do multiple so upsert seems favourite.

What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: You can probably add it in the `$data` for now and maybe open a feature request in Laravel. It does look like something that should be filled in if it's not currently

Comment: When using upsert or insert, the relation foreign key is not set automatically, you need to add it to your inserted data

Comment: From the comments above I have found [this PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/40057) to add this function - which is currently closed due to inactivity